# Load JavaScript in Google App Engine

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, google-app-engine

I got so confused loading JavaScript in [Google App Engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_App_Engine). I am using the Django template.

First, in my **base** HTML file, I can't load my downloaded jQuery code from local say, `d:/jquery.js`, like

```
<script src="d:\jquery.js" type="text/javascript" ></script></head>,
```

This line is in my base HTML file. It works when I load jQuery from **remote**. Like

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"type="text/javascript" ></script></head>
```

I don't know why.

Second, I can't load my own-created JavaScript code to my HTML file. Say I create a JavaScript file, like `layout.js`, and I try to load it like this in my child HTML file, which, by the way, inherits from the **base** HTML.

```
 <body><script src="layout.js" type="text/javascript"></script></body>
```

And it doesn't work at all. The only way it works I have tried is when I put the actual JavaScript code in the body of my base HTML file. Like

```
<body><script>
    $(document).ready(
        $("#yes").click(function() {
            $("#no").hide("slow");
    }));
</script>
```

I don't know why either... How do I fix it?

Comment: Can you word your question more clearly or at least break it up into paragraphs? Also note that \` is the correct character for inserting code rather than *

Comment: How could you seriously expect your front-end code to load scripts from your local machine?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

AppEngine doesn't know anything about paths on your local system; it will only upload files that you configure it to. Do this by having a line like this in your app.yaml file:

```
handlers:
- url: /js
  static_dir: js
```

In this case, `/js` represents a subdirectory of your main project directory, and you can put all of your static JavaScript files in there. They will be uploaded to the production server, and you can include them in your HTML with:

```
<script src="/js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for replying me, but I configured my app.yaml like what you said above, and put all my javascirpt files into the js subfolder. but still I got an error that says 404 not found... **Request URL:http://localhost:8080/js/jquery.js
Request Method:GET
Status Code:404 Not Found**, Thank you

Comment: check the ordering of your url handlers in your app.yaml.  If you don't have the /js handler above the /.*, then the /.* rule will catch all GET requests for anything (including your js directory) before your /js rule gets a chance.